# Не получается найти символьный элемент в структуре

Tags: c++, mingw

Помогите решить проблему с нахождением символьного элемента в структуре. 
Есть объявленная структура, один элемент которой char

```
struct SCORES     // структура данных результатов игры
{
    char Name[16];   // Имя
    int  Total = 0;      // Кол-во игр
    int  Wins = 0;       // Кол-во побед
};
```

Объявленная структура читается и пишется в бинарный файл:

```
bool readfile () // Загрузка результатов из файла
{
    bool success = true;
    int k = 0;

    ifstream ifile("data/score.dat", ios::binary);
    if (ifile.is_open()) // вызов метода is_open()
    {
        // Считывать в цикле, пока не eof
        while (!ifile.read((char*)&tempUser, sizeof(SCORES)).eof())
        {
            arrUsr[k] = tempUser;
            k++;
        }
        ifile.close(); // закрыть прочитанный файл
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Unable to load file data/score.dat \n" << endl;
        success = false;
    }
    return success;
}

bool writefile () // Запись результатов в файл
{
    bool success = true;

    ofstream ofile("data/score.dat", ios::binary);
    if (ofile.is_open())
    {
        for (int k =0; k < KolUser; k++)
        {
            ofile.write((char*)&arrUsr[k],sizeof(SCORES));
        }

        ofile.close();
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Unable to open file data/score.dat \n" << endl;
        success = false;
    }
    return success;
}
```

Ввожу имя игрока :

```
void addName () //Вводим имя игрока
{
    char *tempname = "xXx";
    strncpy(User.Name,tempname,sizeof(User.Name));

    cout << User.Name << "\t" << User.Total << User.Wins << "\tRazmer: " <<sizeof(User.Name)<< endl;
}
```

После чего пытаюсь найти этого игрока в массиве:

```
void addTotal () // Инкремент кол-ва игр пользователя или добавление нового
    {
        bool fnd = false;

        for (int k=0; k < KolUser; k++) //Перебор элементов
        {
            cout << "Massiv: " << arrUsr[k].Name << endl;
            cout << "Polzovatel: " << User.Name << endl;
            if (arrUsr[k].Name == User.Name )
            {
            arrUsr[k].Total++;
            cout << "Nashel" << endl;
            fnd = true;
            break;
            }

        }
        if (!fnd)
        {
            for (int k=0; k < KolUser; k++)
                if (arrUsr[k].Total == 0)
                {
                    arrUsr[k] = User;
                    arrUsr[k].Total++;
                    cout << "Perviu 0" << endl;
                    fnd = true;
                    break;
                }
            if (!fnd)
            {
                arrUsr[KolUser-1] = User;
                arrUsr[KolUser-1].Total++;
                fnd = true;
                cout << "V konez" << endl;
            }
        }

    }
```

Но данный код, ни разу не находит совпадение, а только каждый раз добавляет пользователя xXx как еще не существующего. В результате, весь массив заполнен одним пользователем.

Comment: Имя игрока массив char, значит нужно не оператор == использовать arrUsr[k].Name == User.Name , а  функцию strcmp

Comment: У встроенных массивов нет оператора сравнения. Вместо содержимого массивов в `arrUsr[k].Name == User.Name` сравниваются значения указателей.

Comment: Или использовать std::string вместо массива char

Comment: и не только в этом ощибка...

Comment: @JaponDemon - спасибо, strcmp помог. 
if (strcmp(arrUsr[k].Name, User.Name) == 0 )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо

```
if (arrUsr[k].Name == User.Name) ...
```

попробуйте или через `strstr` — менее надежно если имя в котором происходит поиск содержит в себе искомое:

```
if (strstr(arrUsr[k].Name, User.Name) != 0) ...
```

или правильнее как писали выше `strcmp`:

```
if (strcmp(arrUsr[k].Name, User.Name) == 0) ...
```

При использовании любого варианта строка должна оканчиваться нулем (`0х00`).

Comment: Код заработал верно при использовании if (strcmp(arrUsr[k].Name, User.Name)==0)